# Azure Point to Site VPN

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm looking to test the azure point to site VPN functionality out.

Here is what I'm looking to do :

1. Create Virtual Network
2. Setup point to site VPN
3. Attach one or more Virtual machine to this network.
4. Use the VPN tunnel to connect to these machines from my laptop.

I have been following a great MS article that explains how to create the point to site, but using the classic interface :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/?cdn=disable

I also have been following a great Pluralsight course, this too using the classic interface,

The problem with using the classic interface is that I then end up with a classic Virtual Network and when I try and attach my non classic Virtual machine to this network it's not available as an option (I can see my non classic Virtual networks.)

So my question is, how do I create a point to site VPN using the non classic Virtual Network ? Is this document yet ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you looking to create it? Powershell? ARM Template?

Comment: @Michael B - Via the web interfaces portal, classic and also the new interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from Azure-Quickstart templates: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/f16ae43e7d52001942fc70821ce89c16857448cf/101-point-to-site

The only problem which i was facing: deploying the certificate, this has finally worked via PowerShell CMDlet. Don't be surprised, you will not see the "working" VPN Gateway in Azure-Preview Portal (but hey it works..)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I have found these. I was looking to do the point to site via the portal. Are we saying that this functionality isn't in the new portal and the only way is via the templates ?

Comment: You are right, currently not possible via Preview Portal (;